# Ajaxified links not working after jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I am using this script https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify to ajaxify all of my links.  On one of my pages, I am loading in data using the jquery .load() function.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').load('/load/load-trending-artists.php?n=1', function() { 
        $('img').lazyload({ event : 'load', effect: 'fadeIn'});
        $('.loadmorecontent').show();
    });
});
```

In this script, I am loading a bunch of images and links that go to other pages of my site.  However, when i click on any of these links that have been loaded through jquery .load(), the link is not ajaxified and instead acts normally.  This is a huge problem for me and a large inconvenience to my site.  Is there any way that links loaded through .load() can still be affected by the ajaxify plugin?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you ajaxify the links?

Comment: If you ajaxify the links by attaching a click handler, search for "event delegation" (namely, `$(container).on('click', target, handler)`)

Comment: The links are ajaxified automatically using the script that I mentioned above.  Therefore, i can not figure out why links that are loaded into $('#container') are not working properly.

Comment: you need to explicitly ajaxify the new links that are dynamically loaded via load(). in your callback method, try adding $('#container').ajaxify().  this is what the script does automatically to the entire body when the original page loads ($body.ajaxify())

Answer (score 0):

#### Checkout this one if this helps: http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/demo.php

```
<a id="options" href="#">Setting up options</a>
```

its been ajaxified with this:

```
$('#options').ajaxify({
    link:'example.php?action=options&ajax=true',
    target: '#container',
    loading_img:'images/orange_loading.gif',
    title:'Setting up options', // change page title. Since v2.0
    method:'POST'
});
```